# Make Nokogiri treat xmlns as an ordinary attribute?

Tags: ruby, xml, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I know how to work with namespaces in Nokogiri, but sometimes, I want to look at how the document is actually specified.

In those cases, it would be nice if Nokigiri could simply act like it knows nothing about namespaces, treat "xmlns" just like any other attribute, and treat elements as if their names are exactly as written (colons and all, when present) and all in the default namespace.

Is there a way to achieve that?

EDIT: Add example

So let's say I'm using Nokogiri to check generated SVG. I want to know that the namespace was specified in the root element using the xmlns attribute, and I want to know that the sub-elements use implicit name-spacing.

```
<svg version="1.1" width="300" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M 10,10 l 5,20" />
</svg>
```

If I parse that using Nokogiri, then I can find the "path" element as follows:

```
svg_doc.xpath('//ns:svg/ns:path', 'ns' => "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
```

That shows me that the file is "correct" in terms of resulting in elements with the expected namespaces, but doesn't let me know anything about how that namespacing was specified.

If I could get a document instance that is completely ignorant of namespaces, then…

I could inquire about the "xmlns" attribute value using `svg_doc.root['xmlns']`…

and I could find that there is a "path" element child of the "svg" root element and that neither element has namespace qualifier prefix using `svg_doc.xpath('//svg/path')`.

Comment: You need to show an example of *how* you're searching. Nokogiri supports exactly what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Namespaces" section of "[Searching an HTML / XML Document](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html)" is the part about using CSS selectors:

> Don’t be fooled though. You do not have to use XPath to get the benefits of namespaces. CSS selectors can be used as well. CSS just uses the pipe symbol to indicate a namespace search.
>
> Let’s see the previous search rewritten to use CSS:

```
@doc.css('xmlns|title') # => ["<title>Example Feed</title>", "<title>Atom-Powered Robots Run Amok</title>"]
```

> When using CSS, if the namespace is called “xmlns”, you can even omit the namespace name. That means your CSS will reduce to:

```
@doc.css('title') # => ["<title>Example Feed</title>", "<title>Atom-Powered Robots Run Amok</title>"]
```